# Failing to create client ID, due to duplication of signing fingerprint by another Android OAuth2 client

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, clientid, google-tasks-api

For updating our Android app with newly adding Google Tasks support, we've tried to create new Client ID with our own application's fingerprint and package name.

Unfortunately, it keeps falling with message "The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client." from Google developer console.

But we do not have any other client id already registered with the app's fingerprint. We don't have any deleted project as well. Since our application is being published under open beta. It's really critical for us. Could you please help us?