# Can't link google play game services to an app because the client id is in use. However there is no app using that id

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-play-games

I'm trying yo update a game on google play to support leaderboards and achievements. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rightpedalstudios.dragonseason)

However, when I go to link the app I get the message "This client ID is globally unique and is already in use."

I've searched online for people who have had the same problem and the advice they are given is to delete the client ID in the developer console, and if the app has been deleted there then undelete it first. However, there is nothing in the console using the ID, nor is there any deleted apps. As far as I can tell there is no app using the client id.

I did find another person asking a similar question here that was never answered.
[Failing to create client ID, due to duplication of signing fingerprint by another Android OAuth2 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652546/failing-to-create-client-id-due-to-duplication-of-signing-fingerprint-by-anothe?newreg=ac3e42482e2e4d6f9dd3493dd50c5b99)

I also get the message "The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client." When I try to set up a client ID from the developer console. (I know I'm not meant to do that if I'm using google play games, I just wanted to check if it failed from there too.)

I've tried contacting google support, I was directed to the google API support, and then directed here.

Two other developers that have worked on this project could have somehow created a client ID. Although I have contacted them and neither of them recall creating one.

Is there anyway to find out where this client ID is being used?

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the client id in the Google API console (now confusingly renamed the Google Developers Console !). Then you can link the app to the game straight away. I have just done this, and it worked fine for me. I wanted to link an existing app to a different game, so I deleted both the debug and prod(release) definitions and was able to immediately link the app to the new game.

Note that for many of us, doing work on Google Play Game Services in the Google API console is a last resort - many of us have encountered Google related bugs in the past by doing this !

This image may help:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is that there is nothing in the console that uses the ID. We don't have any deleted projects either.